# How to enable caching on Apache2 (using as load balancer)

Tags: apache-http-server, load-balancer

I'm using Apache 2 as my load balancer (mod_jk).

I've 2 Tomcat servers behind my load balancer.

What I'm trying to do is to enable caching of my static pages in my load balancer using mod_cache but nothing seems to be working. I confirmed this by creating a simple JSP page that prints out current date time and I always get the latest date time (indicating that the JSP page is not cached).

OS: Ubuntu

mem_cache directive:

```
<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>
        CacheEnable mem /
        MCacheSize 4096
        MCacheMaxObjectCount 100
        MCacheMinObjectSize 1
        MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does your current mod_cache directive look like?

Comment: hi, please take a look at my question. I just added the directive there.

Comment: Let's start with the simplest solution, do you have mod_cache.so installed?

Comment: Yes. I followed instructions from here, http://www.howtoforge.com/caching-with-apaches-mod_cache-on-ubuntu-10.04. For mem cache.